# Display information from another model into different view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to display an attribute from one model to another model's view.

My first model(`animal`) has an attribute `animal_num` and I would like to show the information in `animal num` in another view as a collection_select.  The selection will be stored into the attribute `num`.

Here's a snippet of my _form:

```
  <div>
   <%= f.label :num %><br />
   <%= f.collection_select :num, @animal.animal_num %>
  </div>
```

I've made sure that my animal model has a `belongs_to` relationship with my other model.  `num` and `animal_num` are both strings as well.  Still I am getting an error on my page:

```
undefined method `animal_num' for nil:NilClass
```

Any ideas?

Comment: you have to declare `@animal` on particular action if you're using it

Comment: Which file is this snippet from? also post the code for your controller. Mostly the error is because of the action not initializing @animal

Comment: It's from my _form.  Which controller?  animal or my other model's controller?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
  <div>
   <%= f.label :num %><br />
   <%= f.select :num, Animal.all.collect {|c| [c.animal_num] } %>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to link the two models. For example, in Animal, you should have something like this

```
class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :animal_nums
end
```

and on the other model, you should have

```
class AnimalNum < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :animal
end
```

so you won't have « undefined method » when you call animal_nums (use the plural)